# Calculate boxes required

Tags: excel, formulas

I want to make an Excel spreadsheet to help us know how many different boxes we need to order. When a customer places an order of different bottles, we need to know how many boxes we need for each type of bottle.

For example, a customer orders 64 bottles of `x`; 40 bottles of `y`, etc. We know that the boxes for `x` can fit 8 bottles, the boxes for `y` can fit 16 bottles.

What formula can I use to enter the amount of bottles and automatically it would tell me how many boxes of each types we'll have to order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using [`CEILING`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/CEILING-function-f3b5f222-592b-4557-ae9a-05707d756509), something like:

```
=CEILING(BottlesOfX / SizeOfBoxesOfX, 1)
```

For example, `CEILING(40/16,1)` evaluates to `3` (`40/16` is `2.5`, then `CEILING` rounds it up to the next full box).